# Getting a simple KVM switch

Tags: hdmi

I have two laptops.  I'd like to use one keyboard, one mouse, and one monitor.  But the KVM switch that I bought doesn't work.

For both laptops, if I route through the KVM switch then something shows on the monitor, but it is only the background image (in one case it is a graphic and in the other it is just a color gradient).  The files on the desktop, the mouse, and any open windows do not show on the monitor.  Of course, they show on the laptop's screen if I do not use the KVM switch.

One laptop has Ubuntu 18, the other has a very fresh Ubuntu 20.  I use Ubuntu Mate on both.  Any suggestions about how to show the entire desktop (or perhaps a better term is both planes of the desktop?) would be gratefully received.

I'll list the graphic hardware spec for one machine in case it is helpful.  I have a Dell Latitude E5470, with Mesa DR Intel Graphics 530 (SKL GT2).  I am running 1920x1080 at 60 Hz (which I believe is well within the specs of the KVM switch).  It also says that I am running X.  On one laptop I am running the monitor via an HDMI outlet on the laptop.  In the other, I am running via a dvi-to-hdmi adaptor, and then to the HDMI plug into the  monitor (the HDMI port is physically blocked).

For a KVM switch, I bought whatever came up on Amazon.  The box does not have a brand name, it just says "Made in China".   It takes in two computers and outputs to one monitor.

If I need a higher-spec KVM switch, then I'd appreciate a person cluing me in about a good one to buy.  But the fact that it shows the background plane suggested to me that something more is happening.  I'd be very glad for any ideas.

Comment: Do your laptop screens work while they are connected to the KVM? If so go to Settings>Display and see if the monitor is recognized. Then set the monitor to "mirror" the biult-in screen. As for a recommendation of hardware, KVM in this case, it is off-topic in this site.

Comment: Did you try [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier)? I use it and I love it to share my keyboard and mouse between the laptop and the desktop. It is a software based solution.

Comment: You could abandon KVM, network the two computers together, and use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` to display one on the other. Read `man -k ssh`, `man xhost`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping recommendations are off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

The solution, from user68186, was to reset the displays.  I went to the Control Center, selected Displays, and had it Detect the Monitors, then set the display to be the same in both windoww, then Apply.  (This is even though I had already been displaying through this monitor.)